# Unrolling loops in one file

Tags: objective-c, optimization, llvm, loop-unrolling

I'm writing Objective-C code with LLVM. I have one file full of very performance-critical code. Is it possible to turn on compiler optimizations (specifically, loop unrolling) for just this one file, without setting a project-wide value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.  Choose your project file from the project navigator.  Then choose the target.  Click the Build Phases tab.  Open the Compile Sources section.  Double-click the source file of interest and add the compiler flag.  Here's a picture:

[image: compiler flag for one source file]